# Grails application context in javascript library

Tags: grails

Is it possible to access

```
grails.app.context
```

from within a javascript library? --That is, not javascript inserted in a GSP file.

I have som javascripts that are context dependent, why I need to be able to access this from javascript.

I include the javascript in my gsp-files with:

```
<r:require modules="myModule" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass it to Javascript as global JS variable, put this inside `<head>` tag:

```
<g:javascript>
   window.appContext = '${request.contextPath}';
</g:javascript>
```

and use it anywhere from plain javascript, like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: appContext + '/hello/world'
})
```