# How Can I Reference grails.app.context in application.js?

Tags: grails

I want to reference an absolute URL in application.js, but the grails.app.context changes between environments.

How can I reference grails.app.context in application.js?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813217/grails-application-context-in-javascript-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put context into a global JS variable:

```
<g:javascript>
   window.appContext = '${request.contextPath}';
</g:javascript>
```

and use it anywhere from plain javascript, like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: appContext + '/hello/world'
})
```

Comment: Ok, this is what I was doing. I just wanted to double check to see if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer suggested by Igor is good, personally I do prefer to store that information into a meta tag (in a GSP layout) to avoid defining javascript global variables. Something like this:

```
<meta name="appContext" content="${g.resource(dir: '/')}" />
```

So you can retrieve the value from wherever you are in your application. Like this:

```
$('meta[name=appContext]').attr('content');
```

Comment: Pretty neat idea. I'll definitely give it a shot.